# OS versions that support the system allocator for CUDA Unified Memory?

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, cuda

From the slides posted [here](https://www.redhat.com/cms/managed-files/HMM%20for%20SC%20171114_0.pdf), it seems that using the system allocator through calls to `malloc` or `new` instead of Nvidia's `cudaMallocManaged` is only supported on Linux kernel versions 4.14 or newer?...  If so, is there a way to query the Nvidia driver or the CUDA runtime to know whether the system allocator can be used to properly allocate a memory block for use within the CUDA unified memory model? Or would this have to be something where you keep a white-list of operating systems/kernel versions and fallback to the traditional `cudaMallocManaged` if the detected operating system is not on the white-list?  If the latter, does anyone know of an approved white-list of operating system versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I ran into this problem, because I thought my system was supported, but it's not.  Long story short, since this "feature" seems to require a perfect storm of compatible hardware and software, I am sticking to the old API.  I know that is probably not the answer you wanted.

If you really want to use `malloc` or `new`, I would say your query would be a combination of:

1. Asking the OS what kernel version its running.  See the `uname` syscall.
2. Running `deviceQuery` (or similar) to check for CUDA version (8.0 or better) and GPU (looking for compute capability greater than or equal to 6.0).

More info regarding OS support can be found here: https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=HMM-In-Linux-4.14.  It does seem that kernel version 4.14 or greater should have this feature.